# Python - separate dataframes by groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I'm trying to download multiple stock data and compile it into different dataframes automatically. So far, I've been able to get all the information into a single dataframe, then separate it by the stock's symbol. But when I try to separate it into different dataframes my code will only include the first symbol's data.

My code below:

```
start = dt.datetime(2016,8,17)
end = dt.datetime(2019,12,23)
list_of_tickers = ['DELL', 'GRPN', 'EBS']
p = web.DataReader(list_of_tickers, 'stooq', start, end)
res = p.stack().reset_index()
res.columns.names = [None]
res.index.names = ['ID']

stockdata = res.groupby('Symbols')
for Symbols, Symbols_df in stockdata:
    data = pd.DataFrame(Symbols_df)
```

The output:

```
1    2014-12-24    GRPN  7.8900  8.0710  7.8700  8.01   4034314.0
3    2014-12-26    GRPN  8.1400  8.4300  7.9400  7.95  17556775.0
5    2014-12-29    GRPN  8.2500  8.4300  8.1000  8.13  10452505.0
7    2014-12-30    GRPN  8.2200  8.3100  8.1200  8.21   9087772.0
             ...     ...     ...     ...     ...   ...         ...
2754 2019-12-18    GRPN  2.3900  2.4400  2.3800  2.42   4646022.0
2757 2019-12-19    GRPN  2.2750  2.3996  2.2400  2.39  11905805.0
2760 2019-12-20    GRPN  2.2300  2.2900  2.2100  2.28  11355706.0
2763 2019-12-23    GRPN  2.2550  2.2700  2.1700  2.25   6493660.0
```

But my desired output would be 3 different dataframes, where each would be a different stock's info.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

edit: For more info, the future goal is to upload this stock data to a sql server, prompting that each dataframe should be unique.

Unless there is a way to accomplish that without separating?

Comment: list_of_tickers  determine different dataframes??

Comment: list_of_tickers is a variable that is used to retrieve stock values in datareader (p)

Answer (score 0):

Probably this example can help you:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """
A,B,C
5d8a,N,DELL
5d8b,A,DELL
5d8c,B,GRPN
5d8b,C,GRPN
5d8f,Y,EBS
5d8b,X,EBS
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=',')
for x, y in df.groupby('C'):
    print(y)
```

Result:

```
#Df1
      A  B     C
0  5d8a  N  DELL
1  5d8b  A  DELL
#Df2
      A  B    C
4  5d8f  Y  EBS
5  5d8b  X  EBS
#Df3
      A  B     C
2  5d8c  B  GRPN
3  5d8b  C  GRPN
```

Comment: I see how that would work with an initial list. I think I found a manual solution where I set dataframes: for example:

grpn = stockdata.get_group('GRPN')

but I would preferably like to automate that process